# Crashlytics was unable to completely start up

Tags: android-studio, twitter-fabric

Currently i have some issue with Fabric plugin for Android Studio.

After installing Fabric plugin for Android Studio when i'm trying to access fabric through the toolbar icon inside IDE it's been grey out.

I have already tryed to Deinstall / reinstall fabric plugin.

When i'm looking at the idea.log i have the following error inside of it.
Do you have any idea and what could be wrong?

> 2017-11-21 00:16:02,280 [se-915-b01]   INFO - ols.intellij.CrashlyticsPlugin - Crashlytics 4.1.1 initialized for Android Studio 3.0 
>   2017-11-21 00:16:03,278 [d thread 2]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionPreloader@433d2a21 
>   2017-11-21 00:16:03,364 [se-915-b01]  DEBUG -                    Crashlytics - -------------Crashlytics appending to Intellij Logger------------- 
>   2017-11-21 00:16:03,400 [se-915-b01]   WARN -                    Crashlytics - Crashlytics was unable to completely start up. 
>   com.crashlytics.api.storage.exception.UnsupportedVersionException
>       at com.crashlytics.api.storage.Hexifier.get(Hexifier.java:67)
>       at com.crashlytics.api.RestfulWebApiCache.loadFromEncodedCache(RestfulWebApiCache.java:255)
>       at com.crashlytics.api.RestfulWebApiCache.loadCachedOauthUser(RestfulWebApiCache.java:186)
>       at com.crashlytics.api.RestfulWebApi.(RestfulWebApi.java:180)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.core.CoreBundleActivator.init(CoreBundleActivator.java:278)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.core.CoreBundleActivator.start(CoreBundleActivator.java:140)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2154)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2072)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:976)
>       at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:963)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.bootstrap.osgi.OsgiBootstrapper.loadComponents(OsgiBootstrapper.java:155)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.OSGiPluginServices.loadComponents(OSGiPluginServices.java:139)
>       at com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.CrashlyticsPlugin.initComponent(CrashlyticsPlugin.java:90)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:491)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:120)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:466)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:176)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:556)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:501)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:66)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:163)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:473)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:104)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:425)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:411)
>       at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:206)
>       at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:49)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:343)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)